# DIV должен заполнить ячейку таблицы

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как видно на картинке во второй ячейке после второго дива есть пустое место. Так вот не могу понять каким образом второй див заставить по высоте вытянуться до конца ячейки.

[image]

Код таблицы:

```
<style>
.div_100 {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    overflow: auto;
}
.simple_div {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 25px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="simple_div">asdasdasd</div>
        <div class="simple_div">asdasd</div>
        <div class="simple_div">asdasd</div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <div class="simple_div">asdasdasd</div>
        <div class="simple_div">asdasd</div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="div_100">sdasd</div></td>
    <td><div class="div_100">asdasd</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

В идеале хотелось бы решить проблему без скриптов. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо скрипт, либо смена верстки, либо мириться с отсутствием нижнего бордюра.

```
td {overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top}
td > div:last-child{
    padding-bottom:32767px;
    margin-bottom:-32767px;
}
```

ЗЫ Теория и практика здесь: [In Search of the One True Layout](http://fu2k.org/alex/css/onetruelayout/example/interactive). Правда там не таблицы, но смысл тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Если решать проблему без скриптов то можно немного поменять структуру div-ов в таблице http://jsfiddle.net/NFssa/

```
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="simple_div">1</div>
        <div class="simple_div">2</div>
        <div class="simple_div">3</div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">

        <div class="div_100">
           <div class="simple_div">4</div>                    
            5
        </div>

    </td>
    <td><div class="div_100">6</div></td>
    <td><div class="div_100">7</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Немного манипуляций с CSS и будет отлично выглядеть.

Comment: так не пойдет... нужна именно такая структура как в примере, т.е. несколько дивов подряд с текстом

Answer (score 0):

тут нет Javascript ( даже CSS не вижу )
тут чистый HTML 
почитайте 
http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tablitsy/obedinenie-yacheek
http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/colspan
так как у вас не правильно оформлена таблица ( поменяйте структуру кода HTML )
так как без Дивов тут будет на много легче 
или плностью на див-верстке сделать этот элемент

Comment: при чем тут объединение ячеек?
нужна именно такая структура

Answer (score -1):

А нельзя ли просто сделать для тех дивов которых 2 высоту 50% или у вас их может быть и 1 и 2 и 3 и у каждого должен быть один класс?

Comment: там подряд сколько угодно может быть дивов в любом из столбцов. поэтому надо чтоб последний в каждом из них растягивался до низу...

Comment: А может тогда

.simple_div{
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
?

Comment: пробовал... не хочет